# Cycles Render Engine Missing v2.74

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

After upgrading from 2.73 to 2.74, I no longer have the Cycles Render Engine available. It shows that it is enabled in the User Preferences Add Ons. I am using the Windows version, 64-bit. I am running Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit.

Comment: C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.74\config and deleted userpref. The file must have been corrupted.